# arrange dom order using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="grape">grape</div>
<div id="apple">apple</div>
<div id="orange">orange</div>
```

I have an array `fruits = ['apple','grape','orange']`, how to alter above dom according to the order of my array?

Comment: Do you have to order the existing elements or can you just replace what you have with new elements that have the order you want?

Comment: @jfriend00 the dom has already existed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a parent element

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="grape">grape</div>
    <div id="apple">apple</div>
    <div id="orange">orange</div>
</div>
```

then

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'grape', 'orange'];

jQuery(function () {
    var $p = $('#parent');
    $p.children().sort(function (a, b) {
        return fruits.indexOf(a.id) - fruits.indexOf(b.id)
    }).appendTo($p)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w1qqsa96/)

Comment: @Arun P Johny it works great can you share some information of how it works?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I didn't understand why append replacing the exists and not add, so the sort empty the content of the parent?

Comment: @talsibony because we are using the same dom elements, we are not creating any new elements so those elements will be removed from its original location and will be added to the new location... so effectively a relocation will be happening

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks! I think I got it but I will have to have some extra reading about the sort method

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild the content in order pretty easily:

HTML:

```
<button id="go">Sort</button>
<div id="fruits">
   <div id="grape">grape</div>
   <div id="apple">apple</div>
   <div id="orange">orange</div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
var fruits = ['apple','grape','orange'];
$("#go").click(function() {
    var container = $("#fruits");
    container.empty();
    fruits.forEach(function(item) {
        container.append('<div id="' + item + '">' + item + '</div>');
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/muz9tzb6/

---

Or, you can use the fact that the array contains ID values to rearrange the existing elements like this:

```
var fruits = ['apple','grape','orange'];
$("#go").click(function() {
    var parent = $("#fruits");
    fruits.forEach(function(item) {
        $("#" + item).appendTo(parent);
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/39kge2rw/